# Display the item with the largest value (rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

There are two products:

```
[#<WarehousePosition id: 3719518, available_amount: 2, price_with_fee: 0.4968e4>, 
#<WarehousePosition id: 3731603, available_amount: 5, price_with_fee: 0.1159545e5 >]>
```

how can i display the object with the largest `available amount` on the page? (including price and other parameters)

Comment: Two steps: 1. find the largest object, 2. display it. For the first step, you can use `obj = [...].max_by(&:available_amount)`. If you retrieve the objects from a database, you could also order by `available_amount` (descending) and pick the first one.

Comment: Depending on the wider context, you may be able to perform this query using SQL instead of ruby. Something like: `WarehousePosition.order(:available_amount).first`. This may be preferable, as it prevents loading extra data into memory.